# Is it possible to show the motion path of a keyframed camera?

Tags: animation

I have a camera movement animation that I would like to be able to edit by adjusting bezier handles on the camera path in the viewport, but I don't see any camera path in the viewport.  Is there a way to show it?  Thank you!

Comment: If you select the camera and go to it's Object Properties, there expand the "Motion Paths" tab and click on the "Calculate" button.

Comment: Thank you, James!  That gives me a string of dots that is very useful, but is there also a way to get bezier handles at the keyframes that are interactive in the viewport?  If not I can use a combination of the graph and updating the path, but being used to AE, I thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting approach that would be useful, but not in blender to my knowledge.